# Oja's rule on convolutional layer

Tags: weights

The Oja's rule for updating weights is defined as:
$$
\Delta \textbf{w} = \textbf{w}_{n+1} - \textbf{w}_{n} = \eta \textbf{y}_n(\textbf{x}_{n} - \textbf{y}_{n}\textbf{w}_{n})
$$
where $\textbf{x}$ is vector of inputs, $\textbf{y}$ is the vector of outputs and $\textbf{w}$ is the weight matrix that connects the inputs $\textbf{x}$ and outputs $\textbf{y}$ (In neural networks, this connection is reffered to as a fully connected layer).

Is there an established way to implement the Oja's rule for convolutional layers?